# What is the autocovariance of a GARCH process with a constant mean?

Tags: autocorrelation, garch, acf-pacf

What is the autocovariance of a GARCH process with a constant mean?

Answer (score 0):

We will prove that the autocovariance of a GARCH process with a constant mean is zero for all nonzero lags.

A GARCH(r,s) with a constant mean is:
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= \mu, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.D(0,1)
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some probability distribution with zero mean and unit variance.

Autocovariance of $\{x_t\}$ must be zero at all lags $h\neq0$, since
\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(x_t,x_{t-h}) &= \text{Cov}(\mu+u_t,\mu+u_{t-h}) \\
&= \text{Cov}(u_t,u_{t-h}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(u_t u_{t-h})-\mathbb{E}(u_t)\mathbb{E}(u_{t-h}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(u_t u_{t-h})-0\cdot 0 \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\sigma_t\varepsilon_t \sigma_{t-h}\varepsilon_{t-h}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\sigma_t\varepsilon_t \sigma_{t-h}\varepsilon_{t-h}\mid I_{t-1})) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\sigma_t\sigma_{t-h}\varepsilon_{t-h}\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t \mid I_{t-1})) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\sigma_t\sigma_{t-h}\varepsilon_{t-h}\cdot 0) \\
&= 0.
\end{aligned}

Note that $\sigma_t$ is known as of time $t-1$, so we were able to move it outside of $\mathbb{E}(\cdot \mid I_{t-1})$ at some point in the derivation.